# MariaDB event created with schedule not being set as schedule

Tags: mariadb

When I create an event on a schedule, it does not reflect the schedule I've set for it. Why is this happening? I confirmed event_schedule=on is set.

```
CREATE EVENT DeleteExpiredTokens
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO
    DELETE LOW_PRIORITY
    FROM database.remembertokens
    WHERE set_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);


SHOW EVENTS\G:

*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: database
                Name: DeleteExpiredTokens
             Definer: root@localhost
           Time zone: SYSTEM
                Type: ONE TIME
          Execute at: 2023-01-11 13:03:33
      Interval value: NULL
      Interval field: NULL
              Starts: NULL
                Ends: NULL
              Status: ENABLED
          Originator: 1
character_set_client: utf8mb4
collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Expecting Type to be RECURRING. I have tried setting the variable in my.cnf

**UPDATE**:
The syntax was incorrect, thanks to the answer. The following worked:

```
CREATE EVENT DeleteExpiredTokens ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO
    DELETE LOW_PRIORITY
    FROM database.remembertokens
    WHERE set_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set global event_scheduler=ON (not sure if it's a typo, but you set event_schedule=ON)

For recurring events use the following syntax:

```
CREATE EVENT yourevent ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
  STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ...
```

`database` is a reserved word, preferable use another name for your schema or quote it with backticks.

Comment: I was just anonymizing the request, the actual DB name is different. I will try this.

Comment: Thank you, the syntax was the issue.